# Range hood with worrisome ventilation set up in Hong Kong

Tags: ventilation, stove, fire-hazard, hood

I just took a new apartment in Hong Kong where I didn't notice the way the stove ventilation was set up. The landlord used a discount department store contractor who installed the Siemens range hood and some kind of soft aluminum hose that runs up into a cabinet, across into another cabinet and then out the window of an alcove (so not the greatest air circulation). What really bothered me is that the electrical cord to the stove's hood runs along the same path. At some point the cord and hose are right next to one another. I'm trying to explain why this is dangerous. (Yes, here you often need to explain that their incredibly non-code way of doing things are terrible safety practices.) What is the best fix to this situation? Thank you.

Comment: What part of this set up do _you_ think is dangerous and why? If the power cord is properly insulated, this doesn't sound like a problem at all to me. What is your concern beyond "seems dangerous"?

Comment: The cord crosses twice past the hose -- once underneath and once when they're both looped around a high hole between the cabinets. At one point the electrical cord is touching the aluminum hose. Not a problem?

Comment: As long as the insulation on the electrical cord is intact, it's fine that it would loop around and touch metal.

Comment: Unless the aluminum hose (vent pipe) is getting exceedingly hot, like 60°C or more, there's nothing to worry about. If it's getting that hot, TBH, there are bigger concerns.

Comment: Thank you all very much. Is there anything I should monitor over the coming months, anything that may show wear and therefore, an issuse?